# Ленты новостей rss

Tags: rss

Здравствуйте! Есть ли какие-то ограничения в длине текста по выводу кратких описаний в rss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все делают по стандарту. Либо 250 символов, либо уж немного больше, чтобы текст читался :)

А так никогда не задавался вопросом таким.